# When to use translate and when relocate - What is the difference between translate and layout coordinates?

Tags: javafx-2, javafx-8

When to use translate and when relocate in order to move a node? In the end of the day it seems they do the same thing (visually); move the node;  the first by doing a translation on the origin (the x, y stays the same), the second by changing the x, y coords.
So suppose i want to move a node in a specific point in the screen.. should i use node.relocate(x,y) or node.setTranslateX(x), node.setTranslateY(y)?

To demostrate what I mean I have made a sample program you can play with:
A rectangle on the screen, whose position is determined by 4 sliders (2 of them controlling the layout x, y the other two controlling the translate x, y).

```
/* imports are missing */  
public class TransReloc extends Application{
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Group root = new Group();
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(100, 50, Color.BLUE);
        root.getChildren().add(rect);
        VBox controlGroup = new VBox();
        Slider relocX = new Slider(-100, 100, 0 );
        Slider relocY = new Slider(-100, 100, 0 );
        Slider transX = new Slider(-100, 100, 0 );
        Slider transY = new Slider(-100, 100, 0 );
        rect.layoutXProperty().bind(relocX.valueProperty());
        rect.layoutYProperty().bind(relocY.valueProperty());
        rect.translateXProperty().bind(transX.valueProperty());
        rect.translateYProperty().bind(transY.valueProperty());
        controlGroup.getChildren().addAll(relocX, relocY, transX, transY);
        root.getChildren().add(controlGroup);
        controlGroup.relocate(0, 300);
        Scene scene  = new Scene(root, 300, 400, Color.ALICEBLUE);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`layout` coordinates are used by Layout Managers like StackPane or VBox to control their children location. Group (and Pane) leaves children layout to developer thus there is no difference from `translate` functionality.

So generally you should only change `translate` coordinates for fine location tuning and leave `layout` to layout managers (actually you can't change layoutX, layoutY for nodes inside non Group/Pane layout managers)

As an example try to run next code and resize window to see how StackPane recalculates `layoutBounds`

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(100, 50, Color.BLUE);
    root.getChildren().add(rect);
    Scene scene  = new Scene(root, 300, 300, Color.ALICEBLUE);

    rect.layoutXProperty().addListener( (e) -> {
        System.out.println(rect.getLayoutX() + ":" + rect.getLayoutY());
            });

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

}
```

Comment: So a drawing app that places shapes on a Pane and lets the user drag them around should use setLayoutX/Y or relocate, not setTranslateX/Y?

Comment: @silvali, I'd say it's vice versa :)

Answer (score 1):

Another difference is that when you call **Node.getBoundsInLocal()**, will calculate the LayoutX, LayoutY and all the applied Effects. But, **Node.getBoundsInParent()** will get calculated with LayoutX, LayoutY, *all applied Effects* plus all transformations (rotation, translation and scaling). So you can use **LayoutX/Y** properties as a main position and use **translateX/Y** as a second or an alternative way to move the node. And the other difference is discussed above, I mean not to copy from Sergey Grinev.