# JavaFX resize children relative to parent

Tags: java, javafx, resize, autoresize

Within a resizable Pane that shows an imageView i'd like to select multiple rectangles.

To do so I created a class SelectableImageViewPane. The two classes [ImageViewPane](https://github.com/BITPlan/com.bitplan.javafx/blob/master/src/main/java/com/bitplan/javafx/ImageViewPane.java) and [RubberBandSelection](https://github.com/BITPlan/com.bitplan.javafx/blob/master/src/main/java/com/bitplan/javafx/RubberBandSelection.java) are from the com.bitplan.javafx Project where I am a committer.

When the window is resized the relevant panes are resized nicely as you can see from the debug output produced by e.g. [SelectableImageViewPaneDemo](https://github.com/BITPlan/com.bitplan.javafx/blob/master/src/test/java/com/bitplan/javafx/stackoverflow/SelectableImageViewPaneDemo.java) and the following example screenshots. Unfortunately the selection rectangles are not resized / repositioned.

[image]
[image]

**How could i make sure the child - rectangles are resized/repositioned relative to the surrounding glasspane and in sync with the ImageViewPane/ImageView?**

```
package com.bitplan.javafx;

import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javafx.geometry.Bounds;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;

/**
 * an ImageViewPane with a RubberBandSelection that properly resizes the rectangles
 * @author wf
 *
 */
public class SelectableImageViewPane extends StackPane {
  protected static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger("com.bitplan.javafx");
  public static boolean debug=true;
  private RubberBandSelection selection;
  private ImageViewPane imageViewPane;
  private Pane glassPane;

  /**
   * get my selection
   * @return
   */
  public RubberBandSelection getSelection() {
    return selection;
  }

  /**
   * show the bound of the given node with the given title
   * @param title
   * @param n
   */
  public void showBounds(String title,Node n) {
    if (debug) {
      Bounds b = n.getLayoutBounds();
      LOGGER.log(Level.INFO,String.format("%s: min %.0f,%.0f max %.0f,%.0f",title,b.getMinX(),b.getMinY(),b.getMaxX(),b.getMaxY()));        
    }
  }

  @Override
  protected void layoutChildren() {
    super.layoutChildren();
    int index=1;
    if (debug) {
      showBounds("pane",this);
      showBounds("imageViewPane",imageViewPane);
      showBounds("glassPane",glassPane);
      showBounds("imageView",imageViewPane.imageViewProperty().get());
    }
    for (Node n:selection.selected) {
     showBounds(""+(index++),n);
    }
  }

  /**
   * create me
   * @param imageView
   */
  public SelectableImageViewPane(ImageView imageView) {
    imageViewPane=new ImageViewPane(imageView);
    getChildren().add(imageViewPane);
    StackPane.setAlignment(imageViewPane, Pos.CENTER);
    glassPane = new AnchorPane();
    glassPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);");
    getChildren().add(glassPane);
    //glassPane.prefWidthProperty().bind(imageViewPane.widthProperty());
    //glassPane.prefHeightProperty().bind(imageViewPane.heightProperty());
    selection = new RubberBandSelection(glassPane);
    selection.setSelectButton(true);
  }

}
```

**Update**
In the meantime [I modified RubberBandSelection](https://github.com/BITPlan/com.bitplan.javafx/commit/2654574f2ffe370ebcb2c377d6b64b872d9a806a) to remember the relative bounds of the rectangles within the parent (which I'll need later anyway when using the rectangles in my application). This information can be used to properly layout the rectangles in the parent should the parent's dimension change.

```
Bounds rB = s.relativeBounds;
                double w = getWidth();
                double h=getHeight();
                double minX=rB.getMinX()*w;
                double minY=rB.getMinY()*h;
                double width=rB.getWidth()*w;
                double height=rB.getHeight()*h;
                layoutInArea(s.node, minX,minY,width,height, 0, HPos.LEFT,
                          VPos.TOP);
```

The solution works better but there is still some issue probably involving the x/y offset within the parent.

**Updated SelectableImageViewPane**

```
package com.bitplan.javafx;

import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import com.bitplan.javafx.RubberBandSelection.Selection;

import javafx.geometry.Bounds;
import javafx.geometry.HPos;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.geometry.VPos;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;

/**
 * an ImageViewPane with a RubberBandSelection that properly resizes the
 * rectangles
 * 
 * @author wf
 *
 */
public class SelectableImageViewPane extends StackPane {
    protected static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger("com.bitplan.javafx");
    public static boolean debug = true;
    private RubberBandSelection selection;
    private ImageViewPane imageViewPane;
    private Pane glassPane;

    /**
     * get my selection
     * 
     * @return
     */
    public RubberBandSelection getSelection() {
        return selection;
    }

    /**
     * show the bound of the given node with the given title
     * 
     * @param title
     * @param n
     */
    public void showBounds(String title, Node n) {
        if (debug) {
            Bounds b = n.getLayoutBounds();
            LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, String.format("%s: min %.0f,%.0f max %.0f,%.0f", title, b.getMinX(), b.getMinY(),
                    b.getMaxX(), b.getMaxY()));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void layoutChildren() {
        super.layoutChildren();
        int index = 1;
        if (debug) {
            showBounds("pane", this);
            showBounds("imageViewPane", imageViewPane);
            showBounds("glassPane", glassPane);
            showBounds("imageView", imageViewPane.imageViewProperty().get());
        }
        for (Selection s : selection.selected.values()) {

            if (debug) {
                showBounds("" + (index++), s.node);
                LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, s.asPercent());
            }
            Bounds rB = s.relativeBounds;
            double w = getWidth();
            double h=getHeight();
            double minX=rB.getMinX()*w;
            double minY=rB.getMinY()*h;
            double width=rB.getWidth()*w;
            double height=rB.getHeight()*h;
            layoutInArea(s.node, minX,minY,width,height, 0, HPos.LEFT,
                      VPos.TOP);
        }
    }

    /**
     * create me
     * 
     * @param imageView
     */
    public SelectableImageViewPane(ImageView imageView) {
        imageViewPane = new ImageViewPane(imageView);
        getChildren().add(imageViewPane);
        StackPane.setAlignment(imageViewPane, Pos.CENTER);
        glassPane = new AnchorPane();
        glassPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);");
        getChildren().add(glassPane);
        // glassPane.prefWidthProperty().bind(imageViewPane.widthProperty());
        // glassPane.prefHeightProperty().bind(imageViewPane.heightProperty());
        selection = new RubberBandSelection(glassPane);
        selection.setSelectButton(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: basically, you need to "anchor" the rectangle on the image (f.i. the leading upper corner), then transform the anchor along with the image and move the resized rectangle to that transformed anchor (couldn't try, obviously, as you didn't provide a [mcve] ;)

Comment: @kleopatra - thx for looking into this. Currently I am looking into an approach that remembers the relative position within the parent and uses that to layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two main ingredients to make this working:

1. Tracking the size of the image - I modified [ImageViewPane](https://github.com/BITPlan/com.bitplan.javafx/blob/master/src/main/java/com/bitplan/javafx/ImageViewPane.java) accordingly.
2. making sure the selected rectangles within the image are resized in sync with changes of the Image. The RelativePane below is a helper class in which the rectangles (buttons in fact) can be positioned relatively.

[image: Selection]
[image: Resized]

Please note that there are two changes to the original code by chriscamacho:

- the relative positions are from 0.0 to 1.0 instead of using percent
- instead of translateX/Y layoutX/layoutY are used see also [When to use translate and when relocate - What is the difference between translate and layout coordinates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28835920/when-to-use-translate-and-when-relocate-what-is-the-difference-between-transla)

**RelativePane**

```
package com.bitplan.javafx;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javafx.beans.Observable;
import javafx.geometry.BoundingBox;
import javafx.geometry.Bounds;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.control.Control;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;

/**
 * We want a Pane that will automatically resize its components The components
 * width height and position are all expressed as a relative of the width and
 * height of the Pane from 0.0 to 1.0 As the Pane resizes the position and sizes
 * will all remain relative to the Pane's new width and height. Aspect ratio is
 * not respected
 * 
 * see https://gist.github.com/chriscamacho/4f8b2e3e8f8340278b7c
 * 
 * @author chriscamacho
 * @author wf - modified to relative instead of percent
 *
 */
public class RelativePane extends Pane implements RelativeSizer {
  protected static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger("com.bitplan.javafx");
  public static boolean debug=false;

  /**
   * helper class to keep track of relative position
   */
  public class ControlBundle {
    public double rx, ry, rw, rh;
    public Control control;

    /**
     * construct me for the given control c and the given relative positions
     * 
     * @param c
     * @param rX
     * @param rY
     * @param rW
     * @param rH
     */
    ControlBundle(Control c, double rX, double rY, double rW, double rH) {
      control = c;
      rx = rX;
      ry = rY;
      rw = rW;
      rh = rH;
    }
  }

  Map<Control, ControlBundle> controls = new HashMap<Control, ControlBundle>();

  /**
   * create a relative Pane
   */
  public RelativePane() {
    super();
    widthProperty().addListener(o -> sizeListener(o));
    heightProperty().addListener(o -> sizeListener(o));
  }

  /**
   * show the bounds of the given node with the given title
   * 
   * @param title
   * @param b
   */
  public static void showBoundsPercent(String title, Bounds b) {
    LOGGER.log(Level.INFO,
        String.format("%s: min %.0f%%,%.0f%% max %.0f%%,%.0f%%", title,
            b.getMinX() * 100.0, b.getMinY() * 100.0, b.getMaxX() * 100.0,
            b.getMaxY() * 100.0));
  }

  /**
   * show the given bounds with the given title
   * 
   * @param title
   * @param b
   */
  public static void showBounds(String title, Bounds b) {
    LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, String.format("%s: min %.0f,%.0f max %.0f,%.0f",
        title, b.getMinX(), b.getMinY(), b.getMaxX(), b.getMaxY()));
  }


  /**
   * listen to a change of the given observable
   * @param o
   */
  void sizeListener(Observable o) {
    int index=0;
    for (ControlBundle cb : controls.values()) {
      index++;
      double w = getWidth() * cb.rw;
      double h = getHeight() * cb.rh;
      double x = getWidth() * cb.rx;
      double y = getHeight() * cb.ry;
      if (debug) {
        showBoundsPercent("r"+index,new BoundingBox(cb.rx,cb.ry,cb.rw,cb.rh));
        showBounds("a"+index,new BoundingBox(x,y,w,h));
      }

      cb.control.setPrefWidth(w);
      cb.control.setMinWidth(w);
      cb.control.setMaxWidth(w);

      cb.control.setPrefHeight(h);
      cb.control.setMinHeight(h);
      cb.control.setMaxHeight(h);

      cb.control.setLayoutX(x);
      cb.control.setLayoutY(y);

    }

  }

  /**
   * add a control with the given percentages
   * 
   * @param ctrl
   * @param x
   * @param y
   * @param w
   * @param h
   */
  public void addControl(Control ctrl, double x, double y, double w, double h) {
    this.getChildren().add(ctrl);
    controls.put(ctrl, new ControlBundle(ctrl, x, y, w, h));
  }

  public void removeControl(Control ctrl) {
    this.getChildren().remove(ctrl);
    controls.remove(ctrl);
  }

  @Override
  public Parent getSizer() {
    return this;
  }

}
```